# OST from Tokyo Ghoul:re Episode 2 around 20:40

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

On *Tokyo Ghoul:re* episode 2, there's a song around 20:40.

I already tried SoundHound but no dice.

What is the song title?

Comment: We do not condone illegal source such as the url you provided. Hence I removed it from your question. Please take some time to take [a tour](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a bit more familiar with the A&M ways. Btw, welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Well the OST hasn't been released yet so we don't know the song name + band but I've found a youtube upload of it:
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txpETNVyZFY)

> Soundtrack : Yamada Yutaka / やまだ 豊